# Feeding R seeds into Python code in R/exams

Tags: r-markdown, r-exams

I am writing exams in R/exams but using the `reticulate` R package to write code in Python for the R markdown files (my scripts for generating the data were written in python, but I couldn't find a good python version of R/exams).

This all works fine except the R/exams seeds are not effective, presumably because they are passed to R but not to the Python code in the R markdown file, which itself uses `random` to generate random sets of data.

Is there a way to set the seeds in R/exams when I have data generated by Python code?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a more elegant way to do this but a simple poor man's solution would be to generate a random number for the seed in R and simply pass that on to Python, e.g., `py_set_seed(round(runif(1) * 1e9))`.  But maybe there is a better way to do this...

Comment: Also, I would be interested in an example for an exercise like this. Preferably with a simple enough story that many R/exams users can understand - and with tools in Python that in some way better/easier to use than the corresponding functions in R.

Comment: Have you had the chance to look at this solution, does it also work for your examples? If so, please accept the answer - or otherwise please refine the question so that it can be resolved here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to generate a random number for the seed on the R side and then pass it on to Python via `py_set_seed()` from the `reticulate` package. This has two benefits:

1. The Python seed is linked to the seed on the R side. Thus, when using `set.seed(...)` prior to some `exams2xyz(...)` yields reproducible output for all exercises including those generated in Python.
2. The state of the random number generator in R is also altered. Thus, when drawing several random versions of the same Python-based exercise successively, this leads to different random versions because a different seed is used every time.

A worked example is provided below. Here, we use a random seed between `0` and `1e8` which should be sufficiently large;

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
seed <- round(runif(1) * 1e8)
reticulate::py_set_seed(seed)
```

```{python, include = FALSE}
import numpy as np
values = np.random.normal(size = 4)
values.sort()
```

Question
========

Which of the following `r length(py$values)` values is the smallest?

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
exams::answerlist(round(py$values, 3), markup = "markdown")
```

Meta-information
================
exname: numpy random normal
extype: schoice
exsolution: `r exams::mchoice2string(py$values == min(py$values))`
exshuffle: TRUE
````

Answer (score 1):

Thx for the great pointer. I am able to match this python code

```
np.random.seed(370)
dice = np.random.randint(1,101,3)
print(dice)#[82 41 12]
```

with the output of this exams Rmd file:

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
library(reticulate)
seed = sample(seq(10,500,by=10),1)
reticulate::py_set_seed(seed)
```

```{python numpy code, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
import numpy as np
dice = np.random.randint(1,101,3)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
sol = py$dice
```

Question
========

Toss a 100-face die $3$ times in python using the appropriate numpy function `randint`.
Make sure to execute **np.random.seed(`r seed`)** just before the call to `randint`.

Questionlist
------------
* First toss?
* 2nd toss?
* 3rd toss?


Solution
========

Solutionlist
------------
*   $= `r sol[1]`$
*   $= `r sol[2]`$
*   $= `r sol[3]`$
````