# Autograding of NOPS exams: Implementation & extension to string questions?

Tags: r, evaluation, r-exams

We are using R/exams to create tests in Canvas and TestVision.

We have other forms and other software to perform written exams.

I know R/exams has a great NOPS feature and was wondering:

1. What software is used to autograde the NOPS forms?
2. Can that software also evaluate string questions?

Now it looks that the NOPS form doesn't make it easy for software to read parts. Ideally the software would be adapted so adapted NOPS forms (changes in blue) could read more easily Student Name, and string questions:

[image: extended NOPS form]

Comment: Did the post below answer your question? If so, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left of the post. If not, please refine the question so that it can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### NOPS format

The NOPS forms have not been designed by us but they follow the format that our university has been using. We simply mimicked their format because we initially just generated the PDF files ourselves but used the commercial scanning software of our university.

#### Scanning

However, over the years we have written our own scanner implementation in R in `exams::nops_scan()`. The basic approach is to convert PDF pages to PNG images, read these into R, convert them to black and white pixel matrices, find the scanner markings in the corners, and then extract just the boxes relative to these markings. The boxes either contain printed digits in a fixed font for which a simple decision tree yields a reliable classification - or the boxes are empty/filled vs. checked which can also be classified reasonably reliably. The result is stored in a simple text format that was again not developed by us but to be fully compatible with the commercial system that our university used.

#### Grading

Based on the scan results the function `exams::nops_eval()` computes points and grades. Various evaluation strategies can be plugged in and starting from version 2.4-0 the reports generated by the function can be customized.

### Extension to OCR

At the moment no OCR (optical character recognition) is used, except for the simple task of recognizing printed numbers in a fixed font. But no hand-written characters or digits are ever evaluated automatically. I had played around with this a little bit using `tesseract` but the results were not reliable enough for our purposes.

The string questions that are currently supported are intended for open-ended questions. Hence students get a reasonable amount of space to write something down. The teacher can then grade the answer sheet manually, again by ticking boxes only, which can be read rather reliably. The scanned images of the full sheet are included in the report for the students so that they can also see any hand-written feedback/corrections included in the answer form.

#### Tutorial

A hands-on guide to using the NOPS approach is available at: http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/exams2nops/

#### Misc

Unfortunately, the system is not implemented in a very modular fashion. The reasons for this were two-fold: (1) We followed very closely the given format our university had been using. (2) The bulk of the implementation was written under a lot of time pressure (see the anecdote below). So while the features you propose would be nice to have, they are unlikely to fit well into the current setup. If you would want to have a stab at this, I would recommend to write a modular new implementation, just using the bits and pieces from the existing code that are useful enough.

*Anecdote: Scanning of about 400-500 exam sheets had failed on the university system due to a mistake of the copy shop that had printed the sheets. It was mid-July, everybody was on vacation already including myself. So I sat on my parents porch for two days to write the scanner tool and evaluate the exams that the students were waiting for.*

Comment: Dear Achim, thank you for your very clear and extended answer! I myself will not try to develop extensions in R (at this moment), but maybe within our outside our University there may be some solutions. I hope despite of your extended working-days at your parents porch, you still had a great vacation!

Comment: I enjoy hacking R so this wasn't so bad for a small summer project. And eventually the scanner turned out to be tremendously helpful both for myself as well as many other teachers so it was a good thing. It's just that I wouldn't make all of the design decisions again in the same way...

Comment: Well, we learn as we go! At least I am VERY happy with R/Exams. Also great that it is Open Source. So all kudos to you (and possible others). The only down part is that I hardly know any R, currently I don't have too much additional time (at work) and that there is no good R/Exams alternative written in Python. I think I will have to accept the fact that I have to start learning R... 

Comment: Note that through the powers of R/Markdown you can also write your exercises in Python. It's just that you have to tie them together in R (via `exams2nops`, `exams2moodle`, etc.). For an example see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484148/feeding-r-seeds-into-python-code-in-r-exams