# `nops_eval` is not reading the exam ID, how can I control the exam ID reading?

Tags: r-exams

I have about 400 exams in which I defined a custom ID (using the function `exams2nops`). However, when I use nops_scan none of the IDs is recognized... example:

[image]

An exam sample:
[image]

Is it due to the number of characters in the exam ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the exam ID needs to have exactly 11 digits. I will add a warning about this to `exams2nops()`.

The "culprit" is this line from the internal `read_nops_digits()` function:

```
body(exams:::read_nops_digits)[[6]]
## n <- switch(type, type = 3L, id = 11L, scrambling = 2L)
```

Thus, when reading the `id`, the function expects 11 digits. However, I was pleasantly surprised that if you change this `11L` to `5L` then everything seems to work. You can do so programmatically by making a copy `f` of this function, changing the `11L` to `5L`, and overwriting the function in the `exams` package namespace:

```
library("exams")
f <- exams:::read_nops_digits
body(f)[[c(6, 3, 4)]] <- 5L
assignInNamespace("read_nops_digits", f, ns = "exams")
```

After that running `nops_scan()` should work as needed in your case.

*Additional comment:* Instead of overwriting the `read_nops_digits()` function programmatically as above, you can also modify the function "by hand" using an editor via:

```
fixInNamespace("read_nops_digits", ns = "exams")
```

Comment: Yes, this is a real exam. I have about 400 different ones.

Comment: Thanks for providing a reproducible example off-list. Based on this I was happy to find out that it is relatively easy to work around it. A quick & dirty solution is now provided in my answer.

Comment: The code was more flexible/modular than I had remembered. The reason why the 11 is hard-coded is because it would be otherwise somewhat error prone when trying to auto-detect this. In principle, it might be doable, though. See the anecdote at the end of this post if you want to know why some details of this functionality are not as well-designed as they could be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585337/autograding-of-nops-exams-implementation-extension-to-string-questions/69590815#69590815

Comment: Well... it is incredible the things you can do on your parents' porch in two days of coding. :D

Comment: The code has been much improved since, especially with regard to tweaking the parameters for more reliable results. But I kept the basic approach/design.

Comment: This shows how sometimes the urgency helps to produce great stuff. Is the reason behind the `11L` related to the ID number of your university?

Comment: The 11-digit ID is what the official "LOPS" system of our university is using and which we needed to be compatible with in "NOPS" initially.